# PHP regex question for use in DB

Tags: php, regex, time

I am new to this and had a question.
I have 2 input boxes with times. The values that i get back are 3h 20m 31s.
How do i take this and turn this into 3:20:31 so i can use it in my database ?

Comment: Which server-side language would you use to write the value in the database?

Comment: actually it is used as a fliter so the outcome of this is used in a WHERE statement of a mysql query

Comment: What type of inputs are you using? Standard text inputs or select inputs with defaults (which you should be using)?

Comment: i cant use select inputs with default because its a DB with 390.000 records ! with all different times

Answer (score 1):

No need to use regexes. If you have fixed format you can just do

```
$input = "3h 20m 31s";
$input = str_replace("h ",":",$input);
$input = str_replace("m ",":",$input);
$input = str_replace("s","",$input);
```

Or if you are keen for regexes:

```
$input = "3h 20m 31s";
$regex = "/^\D*(\d+)\D*(\d+)\D*(\d+)\D*$/";
$matches = array();
preg_match($regex, $input,$matches);
echo implode(":",array_slice($matches,1))
```

Comment: I didnt have a fixed format it was just a example. what happens when someone only enters 5s or 4m 3s ? will it still work?

Comment: Not, that won't work. Any other conditions so I could update the answer?

Comment: they need to return as in a h:m:s format. i dont no if that was the case already and if one of them is not given it should say 00 so 34m 5s wil become 00:34:05